# (VK API) Возвращение только своих комментариев в запросе newsfeed.getComments

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Возможно я плохо ознакомился с документацией по VK API, но я уже 6 часов не могу найти отчет на один вопрос.

На запрос:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.getComments
?v=5.12
&last_comments=1
&count=20
&photo_sizes=1
&from=0
&access_token=1234567898765432123456789
&filters=post%2Cphoto%2Ctopic
```

Получаю в ответ комментарии свои и других людей, к постам которые комментировал.
Можно ли получать только свои? Если да, то пожалуйста, укажите на мою ошибку. Cпасибо. 
P.S. Мой комментарий выделен на скриншоте

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, на данный момент такой возможности в VK API нет — Вы можете фильтровать комментарии непосредственно внутри своего приложения.